# is there a standard ruby / rails way to convert "yes","no, "true", "false" to true, false (like yaml does)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am not asking for "humanize boolean".

The scenario in a short:

I have different (html/css) templates, for my customers. This templates are good or not good for different problems. eg. If the template uses a font, that does not support Cyrillic letters, then `cyrillic: no`.

I describe each template with a `yaml`. And within Sub-templates (`scss`) I have a custom function that allows to override the default or base of yaml - description, like this

```
$a: template_description(cyrillic, yes)
```

if this (special) css uses a font that *does* support, even if the basic template does not. You can also think about this like the basic template yaml says  `responsive: yes` but one subdesign is not

```
$a: template_description(responsive, no)
```

So now I have a mixture of `true/false` and `"yes/no"` in my description hash. Sure I can just convert with `if`s, `switch` or more elegant with methods.

I just wonder if there is something built in, just not to reinvent the wheel, because yaml does it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way would be using the humanize boolean gem, there's nothing in the default Ruby library for this.

Comment: The first sentece in my question is 'I am not asking for "humanize boolean".'

Comment: you're asking for the standard way. humanize boolean *is* the standard way. I'm just pointing that out, not suggesting you use it - it seems like overkill for this situation.

You could use the YAML library to interpret yes/no, but again seems like more work and bulk than it's worth.

No, nothing is already built in to ruby to handle this.

Comment: "nothing built in" I thought so,  I just wanted a second opinion. I take the line of code. And accept tomorrow, if no body has an other opinion ;)